# how to generate unique random numbers in php?

Tags: php

I am generating random numbers using php random function, but I want the generated number should be unique and it should not be repeated again.

```
----------
php code
 $number = rand(100,100000); //a six digit random number between 100 to 100000 
echo $number;

----------
```

but I am using this function for multiple times in my code for users so at very rare case there should be a chance of generating same number again. how can i avoid that.

Comment: store number, check if its been used before. only 100% reliable way with random numbers

Comment: What is this being used for?

Comment: to make unique id's for customers

Comment: areyou storing it in a DB? you could use your primary key too

Comment: best way is - 1. make e random number using `rand()`. 2. grab the current timestamp. 3. add a `prefix` that could be a string depending on your business logic. 4. combine these three and get a random unique number! This process ensures better accuracy of not getting the same number.

Comment: There are two approaches that come to mind.  1.) Check the number you generate against your id's in your database and see if it has been used. If it has generate another until one is unique.  2.) Set your id column for unique values and then when you try to insert a unique id that is already in the column it will throw an error.  Just check for the error when you query.  Also,  Does it have to be 6 numbers in length.  I use about 32 with numbers and letters.

Comment: Question: What are you needing this random number for?

Comment: Are u running linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this:

You said you have branches.  The receipt id could look something like this:

```
$dateString = date('Ymd'); //Generate a datestring.
$branchNumber = 101; //Get the branch number somehow.
$receiptNumber = 1;  //You will query the last receipt in your database 
//and get the last $receiptNumber for that branch and add 1 to it.;

if($receiptNumber < 9999) {

  $receiptNumber = $receiptNumber + 1;

}else{
 $receiptNumber = 1;
}
```

Update the receipt database with the receipt number.

```
$dateString . '-' . $branchNumber . '-' . $receiptNumber;
```

This will read:

```
20180406-101-1
```

This will be unique(Provided you do less than 10,000 transactions a day.) and will show your employees easily readable information.

Comment: No problem! Cheers

Answer (score 2):

If you are storing users in DB you should create column [ID] as primary key with auto increment and that would be best solution.

In other case I'd recommend you to simply store all user id's in ascending order from N to M by reading last ID and adding 1 to it because I see no real gain from random order that only adds complexity to your code.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways, example:

```
$freq = [];
$number = rand(100,100000);
$times = 10;
while($times-- > 0)
{
   while(in_array($number, $freq))$number = rand(100,100000);
   $freq[] = $number;
   echo $number . "<br>";
}
```

This will print 10 random unique numbers.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is use timestamp in php as timestamp never cross each other hence it will always generate unique number.You can use `time()` function in php.

The `time()` function is used to format the timestamp into a human desired format. The timestamp is the number of seconds between the current time and 1st January, 1970 00:00:00 GMT. It is also known as the UNIX timestamp.

```
<?php
$t=time();
echo $t;
?>
```

Also you add a `rand()` function and insert it in front of the `$t` to make it more random as if few users work at same time then the timestamp might collide.

```
<?php
$number = rand(100,100000);
$t=time();
$random = $number.''.$t;

echo $random;
?>
```

The above will reduce the chance to timestamp collide hence making the probability of number uniqueness almost 100%.

And if you make your column `unique` in your database then the php wont insert the number hence this bottleneck will ensure you will always get a unique random number.

```
 bill_id not null unique
```

Comment: It's very possible of getting a concurrency issue if two user/process works at the same time!

Comment: yes Erfan you are right about it , therefore another function should be added below to check if the number is equal to the last 10 records if not then insert the number else use a delay function and then insert it .

Comment: Erfan ahmed thankyou and adern how can i make delay function

Comment: last 10 records is not an ideal threshold of checking uniqueness. Moreover checking each time before insertion is also an overhead and performance heavy. Better using a unique constrain at DB on the generated column, say `ran_unq_num not null unique`. I've commented on the questions. That should be enough for him to come up with an answer!

Comment: can you tell why do you need random number because i will edit the answer with respect to your response .

Comment: Dear Adern i have a restaurant while generating bill each time i want to store the data of bill  by creating a row in db using a unique key(random generated).hence a thousand of bills l will generate in my restaurant branches per week so i want each bill should be unique according to it's key. for this purpose i want random numbers so there should be no chance of two bills with same key.

Comment: why do you need random then , what i think is you can go for solutions like fetch last number from database by `SELECT * from table order by id desc limit 1` and then do a `$new = $row['id']+1;` hence `$new` wont be same also it would be better for billing to use sequential series 1,2,3,4,5...

Comment: Dear Adern Nerk i am very thankful to your answer but i have small doubt it is very big in length can't we able to put limited characters to remember bill number easily or to make it look small

Comment: only `last rowId+1` can't help getting concurrency issues as there are many concurrent users. Add some `suffix` and `prefix` with that row id as commented earlier. If you want to make that small with fixed number like - 10/14 digit unique number then you must generate a better `Hast` code.

Comment: @AdernNerk, it gives  E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined variable: time -- at line 6
Exception: Function name must be a string

Comment: Please remove $ from $time() to time()

Comment: @Gufran yeah i didn't see it and made a mistake there , ty for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

[random_int
(PHP 7)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php)

```
<?php
$number =  random_int(100, 100000);
echo $number;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it for something like user id, then you can use `uniqid` for that. This command gets a prefixed unique identifier based on the current time in microseconds.

Here's how to use it:

```
string uniqid ([ string $prefix = "" [, bool $more_entropy = FALSE]] )
```

Where prefix is used if you are generating ids for a lot if hosts at the same time, you can use this to differentiate between various hosts if id is generated at the same microsecond.

more_entropy increases the likeness of getting unique values.

Usage:

```
<?php
/* A uniqid, like: 4b3403665fea6 */
printf("uniqid(): %s\r\n", uniqid());

/* We can also prefix the uniqid, this the same as 
 * doing:
 *
 * $uniqid = $prefix . uniqid();
 * $uniqid = uniqid($prefix);
 */
printf("uniqid('php_'): %s\r\n", uniqid('php_'));

/* We can also activate the more_entropy parameter, which is 
 * required on some systems, like Cygwin. This makes uniqid()
 * produce a value like: 4b340550242239.64159797
 */
printf("uniqid('', true): %s\r\n", uniqid('', true));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

this code must work

some description about code:

1. generate unique id
2. extract numbers form unique id with regex
3. gathering numbers from regex with a loop

```
<?php

$unique = uniqid("",true);
preg_match_all("!\d+!", $unique ,$matches);
print_r($matches);
$numbers = "";
foreach($matches[0] as $key => $num){
   $numbers .= $num; 
}

echo $numbers;
```